expiration date of a JWT token
I have a problem with a JWT token in JS, the question is very simple, I am creating a token as follows
const token = jwt.sign({ usernameCredential }, chave, { expiresIn: "15s" });

I receive this token and store it, after that when validating it, after the expiration date
function verificarToken(req, res, next) {
const token = req.headers.authorization; 

if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token não fornecido' });
}

jwt.verify(token, chaveSecreta, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token inválido ou expirado' });
    } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
    }
});

}
it always remains valid
How to adjust this?

You need to change jwt.sign() parameters
const expiresIn = 15; // 15 seconds
const payload = {
    sub: user.id,
    iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), // Convert from ms to s
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresIn // Correctly using seconds
};
const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { algorithm: 'RS256' });

Demo
Save as server.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

// Load private and public keys
const PRIV_KEY = fs.readFileSync('./keys/private_key.pem', 'utf8');
const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync('./keys/public_key.pem', 'utf8');

const hardcodedUserId = 'chave'; // Replace with your own user ID
const hardcodedPassword = '1234'; // Replace with your own password

const issueJWT = (user) => {
    const expiresIn = 15; // 15 seconds in terms of seconds
    const payload = {
        sub: user.id,
        iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), // Convert from ms to s
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresIn // Correctly using seconds
    };
    const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { algorithm: 'RS256' });

    return {
        token: signedToken,
        expires: expiresIn // You might want to send this value to the client if needed
    };
};

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { userId, password } = req.query;
    const user = {
        id : userId,
        password : password
    };
    // Check if the provided userId and password match the hardcoded values
    if (userId === hardcodedUserId && password === hardcodedPassword) {
        const jwt = issueJWT(user);
        res.send(jwt);
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');
    }
});
app.get('/verify', (req, res) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]; // Bearer TOKEN

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, PUB_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                    res.status(401).send('Token has expired');
                } else {
                    res.status(401).send('Invalid token');
                }
            } else {
                // Attach decoded token to request object
                req.decoded = decoded;

                // For demonstration: directly sending a response here, but you could call next() to pass to another handler
                res.send({ message : 'Token is valid and not yet expired.', decoded : decoded });

                // If you had subsequent middleware or handlers that needed the decoded token:
                // next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('No access token found');
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

Generate RSA Key Pair
Under keys sub-directory
Generate Private Key
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048

Generate Public Key
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem

Result of keys

You can download openssl if not yet install
Install dependencies
npm install express cors jsonwebtoken fs

Run server
node server.js


Get Token by Postman
GET http://localhost:3000/login?userId=chave&password=1234

Save token into an environment variable
Copy this script into Tests tab
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

console.log(jsonData.token);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.token);


Verify Token by Postman
GET http://localhost:3000/verify

Click Authorization tab ,
Select Bearer token and
Enter in token editor control.
{{access-token}}



Check token by jwt.io
Copy from response body of Postman and Paste it to jwt.io at Encorded section.
You can see payload on PAYLOAD:DATA section.
iat and exp claim name values.

Expired
If call verify endpoint after more than 15 seconds,
will get this message.
Token has expired


